# Dynamic Calculation of Variance after removing an observation

Tags: anova, online-algorithms

I know that there are formulas for calculating variance in dynamic fashions. I have also seen formulas for calculating rolling variances assuming you know what number is leaving and entering the window. 
Is there a formula for calculating variance after removing one or more observations?  I am assuming I won't have access to the full dataset, just the observation I am removing and a handful of aggregated features of the dataset.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The formula is algebraically equivalent to [updating the variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=variance+online) when adjoining a single value to a dataset.